# Forward function composition operator and reverse application operator

Tags: haskell

*(Thank you to Rein Henrichs and  Carsten for the suggestions about a previous post - now deleted.)*

Even if the following is unusual in Haskell, is there something inefficient or untoward in defining forward function composition operator and reverse application operator in this way?

```
> let (?) f g = \x -> g (f x) --  forward function composition operator

> :t (+3) ? (*4)

> (+3) ? (*4) :: Num t => t -> t

> let x ?? f = f x -- reverse application operator
-- For those who have the Haskell Platform 2014.2.0.0 with GHCi version 7.8.3, so Data.Function (&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b is unavailable
```

-- example

```
> "roma" ?? (reverse ? map toUpper ? concatMap (\c -> [c,' ']) ? (++ "- ") ? repeat ? take 3? concat ? (\cs -> take (length cs - 3) cs) ? putStrLn)

> A M O R - A M O R - A M O R 

> :t (reverse ? map toUpper ? concatMap (\c -> [c,' ']) ? (++ "- ") ? repeat ? take 3? concat ? (\cs -> take (length cs - 3) cs) ? putStrLn)
> reverse ? ... ?putStrLn :: [Char] -> IO ()
```

Comment: IIRC, `(??)` is called `(&)` in the lens library, while `(?)` is `(>>>)` from `Control.Category`.

Comment: F# has a "pipe operator" that pipes the value left into the function right of it.  It is written x |> f.  Example "this is a test" |> reverse |> split (==' ') |> map reverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's anything inefficient about the approach. But note that your functions can be defined more easily using `flip` on `.` and `$`:

```
(?)  = flip (.)
(??) = flip ($)
```

also make sure to not forget an `infixl` declaration on your operators (preferrably something coherent with the non-reversed versions).

P.S. I think the names `?` and `??` are highly unintuitive for what they mean.

Comment: You are right, "'?" and "??" are unintuitive. But, are there any other ascii non alphanumeric 1-character available for the task? (I think that "&"  will be available with the next Haskell Platform, so "??" isn't really a problem.)

Comment: I think you can use a preprocessor `if` to check the GHC version and conditionally define your `&`; also, `Control.Arrow` has `>>>` for reverse composition.

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani  correct, it's in ghc 7.10 in Data.Function as &, I've already been using it :)